# Availability of elementry OS 32 bit?

Tags: system

I have a very old Acer Aspire 3000 laptop. is elementary OS available in 32 bit? This is a very simple question. Why can not I post it?

Comment: The Aspire 3000 uses a Sempron+, which *is* a 64-bit processor, but the motherboard maxes out at 2GB of RAM. Given that the integrated video card had just 64MB of memory, you’re going to be limited to *very* lightweight desktops, such as XFCE 

Answer (score 0):

No, elementary is not available in 32 bit.

You may find this useful: https://itsfoss.com/32-bit-linux-distributions/